# Sidebar on the left of the content but after in the dom tree

Tags: css, html, dom-traversal

I need to put a sidebar on the left of the content.

I had this html:

```
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

and I solved using:

```
.sidebar{
    width: 280px;
    float: left
}
.sidebar + .content{
    margin-left: 300px
}
```

For this example: https://jsfiddle.net/VixedS/fcx2aLLa/

But now my that **.content** comes before the **.sidebar**,

```
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
```

how can I obtain the same result **just using css**?

> I don't want to loose the remaining space of the body for the width of **.content** with or without **.sidebar**.

So please remember that before saying to float the **.content** to right. Also, I don't know which page has a **.sidebar**.

Comment: Float the content right? - https://jsfiddle.net/fcx2aLLa/1/

Comment: @Paulie_D I thought about that, but I'll loose the with of it. I mean the remaining space of the parent container (fluid).

Comment: Add the width manually using `calc"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is very powerfull. Works for every browser, any device. Also a great way for responsive design and for a third column.

**Update:**

```css
.container {  
  overflow:auto; 
}

.sidebar {
  width: 280px;
  float: left;
  background: #EEE;
  margin-left: -100%;
}

.content {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.center {
  margin-left: 280px;
}

.container > div:only-child > div.center {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="center">
      Spaghetti
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    Pizza
    <br /> Hobby
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know when the **.sidebar** appears, so how can I always leave a margin to **.center**?

Comment: It already does. Remove the `sidebar` and you will see how it works out.

Comment: Ah if there is no `sidebar`, you want to have the `content` full width?

Comment: Doesn't work, tested right now, of course it will mantain 280px of margin :/

Comment: Check updated answer. I think this is what you want.

Comment: Simply amazing! And it's also supported from IE9.

Comment: add **overflow:auto** in **.containet**

Comment: because I got lost adding a clearfix to prevent the overflow

Answer (score 2):

Do following way. Use `float:right` to `sidebar` and  `display:table` to it's parent.

```css
body {
    display: table;
}
.content {
    float: right;
}
.sidebar{
    width: 280px;
    float: left;
    background:#EEE; // just for this example
}
.sidebar + .content{
    margin-left: 300px
}
```

```html
<div class="content">Spaghetti</div>
<div class="sidebar">Pizza <br /> Hobby</div>
```

Comment: I really like your answer, but please can you explain it a bit for me? Why **display: table** will help me? It's safe for fluid design?

Comment: Ups sorry, but I can't float to right the content, because I don't know when the sidebar appears :(

Comment: @Vixed If sidebar not appear `content ` will move left automatically.

Comment: @Vixed same effect you can achieve using `display:inline-block` instead of `display:table`

Comment: I loose the full width if I float **.content** to right.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox...means you don't have to use floats...and you can re-order the elements as you require.

Support is IE10 and up.

```css
 body {
   display: flex;
 }
 .sidebar {
   width: 280px;
   background: #aaa; // just for this example
   order: 0;
 }
 .content {
   flex: 1;
   order: 1;
   background: plum;
 }
```

```html
<div class="content">
  Spaghetti</div>
<div class="sidebar">Pizza
  <br />Hobby</div>
```

Comment: Must be supported at least from IE8